# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at /x/ base.html

Tags: django, django-templates

django 1.11.3

I have a template does not exist error, to my knowledge I have my template directories setup properly. fleetdb is an app I have in my project with the following directory structure:

```
+ fleetdb
     +templates
         +fleetdb
              -index.html
              -base.html
               (other html pages)
```

Everything was working find until I tried {% extends 'base.html' %} inside my index like so:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'fleetdb/lists.css' %}" />


{% if vehicles_list %}
<ul>
    {% for vehicle in vehicles_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'fleetdb:detail' vehicle.id %}">{{ vehicle.unit }} {{ vehicle.make }} {{ vehicle.vmodel }} {{vehicle.color}}</a></li>
</ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>No Vehicles are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

In my settings.py I have a print(TEMPLATES) statement, and it all seems to be looking in the right areas but not finding base.html. Trace at pastebin: https://pastebin.com/raw/MQDAip64

**Side Question:** How can I inherit templates from another app, would it be like the url tags where `{% url 'fleetdb:detail' }` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try ,

```
{% extends 'fleetdb/base.html' %}
```

Django looks for templates under `templates` sub-directory by default. You have saved yours under `fleetdb` folder under `templates` directory.

Suggestion: If you want to use common templates for more than one apps, then place it under a `templates` directory in your root project folder.

```
+project_folder
    +app1
        +templates
        -----
    +app2
        +templates
        -----
    +templates
        -your-common-templates
        -here-
```

You could then access them from any app within the project.

Comment: Welcome, mate. Anytime!